# SSIS Package Runs without Error - moves no data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a VERY simple SSIS package. It runs against a SQL server database. The begin time is set to DATEADD(hh,-6,GETDATE()) and pulls records, does 2 simple data conversions and drops them in another SQL table.

It's scheduled to run every 6 hours (1 am, 7 am, 1 pm and 7 pm). And it works every time - unless it's 7 pm. At 7 pm, it returns no data and no errors. If I hard code the date as 7 pm it runs without issue and populates the data correctly.

I've tried literally everything I can think of - I've deleted the job and recreated it, I've scheduled it to run at the 4 times specifically, I've scheduled it run every 6 hours. I'm stumped.

Anyone have any thoughts on what my issue might be?

EDIT: 
Here's the code. But it works when I put in 7:00 pm as the time, and it works at every other interval.

```
SELECT AlarmDetail.Priority, Comment.Comment, AlarmDetail.EventStamp, AlarmMaster.GroupName
FROM AlarmDetail 
INNER JOIN Comment ON Comment.CommentId = AlarmDetail.CommentId 
INNER JOIN AlarmMaster ON AlarmMaster.AlarmId = AlarmDetail.AlarmId
WHERE        
AlarmDetail.EventStamp > DATEADD(hh,-6,GETDATE())
AND AlarmDetail.EventStamp < dateadd(hour,13,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate())) 
AND AlarmDetail.AlarmState = 'UNACK_ALM'
AND AlarmDetail.Priority <= 3
```

Comment: Weird... Have you tried SYSDATETIME() instead of getdate()? It doesn't make sense but it's worth the shot

Comment: I've changed it, but I really can't test... until 7 PM tonight. This is maddening.

Comment: See my answer bellow, I think I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the query is wrong. If you execute this code:

```
select DATEADD(hh,-6,cast('2016-06-10 19:00:00' as datetime)), dateadd(hour,13,DATEDIFF(d,0,cast('2016-06-10 19:00:00' as datetime)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2016-06-10 13:00:00.000 2016-06-10 13:00:00.000
```

This condition will always give you an empty result:

```
AlarmDetail.EventStamp > DATEADD(hh,-6,GETDATE())
AND AlarmDetail.EventStamp < dateadd(hour,13,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()))
```

Comment: Yes. This was an incredibly stupid boneheaded mistake after copying some code. I hate when that happens...

Answer (score 0):

You are using spans of 6 hours in your query criteria, AND you are running the job exactly every 6 hours. Since you dont provide sample data and your query, one can only speculate:
 - You need to review your WHERE criteria, and reconsider the fact that milliseconds are important.

Comment: I'm not sure what you means by "reconsider the fact that milliseconds are important." I've posted the code, but it returns data at every other interval than at 7:00:00.000 PM.

Comment: one would need to see the data itself. run some queries on SSMS and verify your results. Results are not determined by your expectations but the data itself. One may say that you get no data because; there is no data to return. none that matches the given criteria anyways. Also the when you query for "EventStamp <" is nto the same as   "EventStamp <=" if you execute at 7 o'clock is would only return values smaller than 7 o'clock (anything at 6 plus some munutes).

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE AlarmDetail.EventStamp > DATEADD(hh,-6,GETDATE())
AND AlarmDetail.EventStamp < dateadd(hour,13,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()))
```

You realize this says, "Where EventStamp is after six hours ago and before today at 1 pm."

Six hours before 7 pm is 1 pm, so if you run it at 7 pm you're looking for EventStamps that are both before 1 pm and after 1 pm.  It will never return anything if it's run after 7 pm.

---

You also need to be mindful that `DATEADD(hh,-6,GETDATE())` still has a time component with minutes and seconds, and no time scheduler is perfectly precise.  If you run it at 1:00:38 PM, you'll get events after 7:00:38 AM.  If the last time you ran the task, it executed at 7:00:05 AM, then there's 33 seconds worth of events that you're missing.  Similarly, if the subsequent run is at 07:00:10 PM, you'll capture 28 seconds of events twice.  Obviously, I don't know what you need it for, but if you're expecting to always capture every event exactly once, this query does not guarantee that.